# Is it possible to have Storm Nimbus Redundancy

Tags: docker, apache-storm, docker-compose

I have search all over the web and the maximum I have found was these two articles:

http://hortonworks.com/blog/fault-tolerant-nimbus-in-apache-storm/

http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/nimbus-ha-design.html

Which poorly explain the instructions to get two or more Nimbus instances running so that if one dies the other takes over... Which makes kinda think if this is at all possible.

Other search results tell me that this is impossible and not required since Nimbus is not a critical node in the cluster. But I hoped for better.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, having multiple Nimbus nodes is not possible:

- https://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/Daemon-Fault-Tolerance.html

It is planed for future released to change the architecture to have stand-by Nimbus instances that take over on failure. Furthermore, it is not strictly required: if Nimbus fails, all running topology resume processing. You can simply restart Nimbus in this case. (Of course, you can automate this by watching the Nimbus process an auto-restart if it dies.)

Of course, as long as Nimbus is down, you cannot interact with the cluster (ie, submit new topologies, stop topologies etc.). However, if you watch dog is fast enough, this "gap of service" should not be too severe.